# Strategies for handling memory consumption in PHP5?

Tags: php, memory

We have a large management software that is producing big reports of all kinds, based on numerous loops, with database retrievals, objects creations (many), and so on.

On PHP4 it could run happily with a memory limit of 64 MB - now we have moved it on a new server and with the same database - same code, the same reports won't come up without a gig of memory limit...

I know that PHP5 has changed under the hood quite a lot of things, but is there a way to make it behave ?

The question at the end is, what strategies do you apply when you need to have your scripts on a diet ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A big problem we have run into was circular references between objects stopping them from freeing memory when they become out of scope.

Depending on your architecture you may be able to use __destruct() and manually unset any references.  For our problem i ended up restructuring the classes and removing the circular references.

Answer (score 6):

When I need to optimize resources on any script, I try always to analyze, profile and debug my code, I use [xDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/), and the [xDebug Profiler](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler), there are other options like [APD](http://php.net/apd), and [Benchmark Profiler](http://pear.php.net/package/Benchmark).

Additionally I recommend you this articles:

- [Make PHP apps fast, faster, fastest..](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-fastapps2/index.html)
- [Profiling PHP Applications](http://www.schlossnagle.org/~george/talks/Profiling-phpworks-2004.pdf) *(PDF)*
- [PHP & Performance](http://ilia.ws/files/frankfurt_perf.pdf) *(PDF)*

Answer (score 0):

Since moving to the new server, have you verified that your MySQL and PHP system variables are identical to the way they were on your old server?

PHP5 introduced a lot of new functionality but due to its backward compatibility mantra, I don't believe that the differences between PHP5 and PHP4 should be causing this large an affect on the performance of an application who's code and database has not been altered.

Are you also running on the same version of Apache or IIS?

It sounds like a problem that is more likely related to your new system environment than to an upgrade from PHP4 to 5.

Answer (score 0):

Bertrand,

If you are interested in refactoring the existing code then I would recommend that you first monitor your CPU and Memory usage while executing reports. Are you locking up your SQL server or are you locking up Apache (which happens if a lot of stress is being put onto the system by the PHP code)?

I worked on a project that initially bogged down MySQL so severely that we had to refactor the entire report generation process. However, when we finished the load was simply transferred to Apache (through the more complex PHP code). Our final solution was to refactor the database design to provide for better performance for reporting functions and to use PHP to pick up the slack on what we couldn't do natively in MySQL.

Depending on the nature of the reports you might consider denormalizing the data that is being used for the reports. You might even consider constructing a second database that serves as a data warehouse and is designed around OLAP principles rather than OLTP principles. You can start at Wikipedia for a general explanation of OLAP and data warehousing.

However, before you start looking at serious refactoring, have you verified that your environments are sufficiently similar by looking at phpinfo(); for PHP and SHOW VARIABLES;
in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

A gig!?!

even 64MB is big.

ignoring the discrepancy between environments, (which does sound very peculiar), it sounds like the code may need some re-factoring.

any chance you can re factor your code so that the result sets from database queries are not dumped into arrays. I would recommend that you construct an iterator for your result sets. (thence you can treat them as array for most purposes).there is a big difference between handling one record at a time, and handling 10,000 records at a time.

secondly, have a look at weather your code is creating multiple instances of the data. Can you pass the objects by reference. (use the '&'). We had to do a similar thing when using an early variant of the horde framework. a 1 MB attachment would blow out to 50MB from numerous calls which passed the whole dataset as a copy, rather than as a reference.

Comment: Objects in PHP5 are passed by reference automatically.

Comment: really?! wouldn't that defeat the idea of scope. if you pass an object to a function, that function is operating on a copy of the object, not the actual object. (unless you pass the object by reference.)

Comment: What @grantwparks has said is a gross simplification...
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

`One of the key-points of PHP 5 OOP that is often mentioned is that "objects are passed by references by default". This is not completely true. This section rectifies that general thought using some examples.`

Comment: It's not operating on a copy of the object; if you make changes to an object passed to a function, the object is changed.  A new "reference/handle/identifier" is created and passed (hence the object isn't passed at all).  The memory used by that reference *should* be irrespective of the size of the object.  What @user1548557 calls a gross simplification, I call the practical effect for all intents and purposes when it comes to addressing the memory.  Just because there's lots of confusion on the php.net page doesn't mean this is complex.

Comment: Unless you explicitly pass a reference the behaviour you are suggesting will only occur under specific circumstances and will not retain the deeper object structure, it's not up for debate the PHP.net docs agree with me, you even describe a process admiting the object is not passed by reference, please review CS101